# How is it valid code in c? It seems to execute fine

Tags: c

The following code seems to execute fine but how is it valid and whats happening here?

```
    int i;
    printf("%d",i["11"]);
```

Comment: UB: `i` is an uninitialized array index.

Comment: There are many questions that this is a duplicate of.  The difficulty is going to be finding them.

Comment: What is with C programmers nowadays? The first thing they are trying to learn is how to abuse the system.

Comment: What is the output..? @manoj

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Here is one of the dupes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a -- the question got 550 upvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does i\[arr\] work as well as arr\[i\] in C with larger data types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181504/why-does-iarr-work-as-well-as-arri-in-c-with-larger-data-types)

Comment: Thanks Ray and nneonneo.  Either of the suggested duplicates would be a better way of closing this question than 'off topic'.  However, as long as it is closed in some way, I'm not going to get too fussed.

Answer (score 7):

`i["11"]` == `*("11" + i)` == `"11"[i]`

Answer (score 1):

when you do `i["11"]` what you do is say to the compiler to take the value of `i` and add to it the value of `"11"` and take the value on the address that is the sum of them