# How is this code functioning inside the computer? P.S - I'm a first year b.tech student

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I do not understand why the "C program" is giving the output `1` in line 1?

```
int main()
{

    static int a[]= {10,20,30,40,50};
    static int *p[]= {a,a+3,a+4,a+1,a+2};
    int **ptr = p;
    ptr++;
    printf("%d,%d",ptr-p,**ptr); //line 1
    return 0;
}
```

I ran the code on CodeBlocks:IDE. The output is `1,40`. I got why `40` part. But I don't understand is why `1`? From my understanding `ptr-p` should give the difference in their address and that should be 4 as in 4 bytes.

Please kindly give a detailed explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Difference in address is typed, means that the unit is the number of places that exists to store things in between. If you understand why ptr++ "points" to 40, then a simple arithmetic will give you the result : ptr++ is ptr=ptr+1, so after increment ptr+1-ptr = 1!

Comment: alternate duplicate : [Pointer subtraction confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not how pointer subtraction works. When you subtract two pointers (belonging to the same array), you get the difference in the subscript, i.e., the element number.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.5.6, P7

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. [....]

That said, the pointer subtraction yields a result of type `ptrdiff_t` and you should use `%td` to print the result.

Comment: You know that this is duplicate, so for the sake of the site, please mark it as is.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I don't think there is a good canonical dupe for this question. The linked ones were quite bad.

Comment: Uh wait I had added such a question to the C FAQ myself... [Why does int pointer '++' increment by 4 rather than 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610298/why-does-int-pointer-increment-by-4-rather-than-1).

Comment: @Lundin : [Pointer subtraction confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238482/pointer-subtraction-confusion) isn't too bad either (found it too late)

Comment: @Lundin This is a standard recurrent question answered at least fifty times...

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is done on "pointed-at items", not on bytes. If you have `int* ptr = array; ptr++;` then `ptr` is increased by `sizeof(int)` bytes.

In your case, which is some seriously obscure code, pointer arithmetic is done on a `int**`. The difference between `p` and `p+1` is `1` item (1 `int*` pointer item). So you get the result `1`.

If you want to know the difference in bytes, you could print the addresses:

```
int **ptr = p;
printf("%p\n", ptr);
ptr++;
printf("%p\n", ptr);
```