# Why does C correctly output an integer when I only allocate 1 byte for it?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I've been digging into memory allocation and pointers in C. I was under the impression that if you do not allocate enough memory for a value and then try to put that value in that memory cell, the program would either crash or behave incorrectly.
But what I get is a seemingly correct output where I'd expect something else.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // Here we intentionally allocate only 1 byte,
    // even though an `int` takes up 4 bytes
    int * address = malloc(1);

    address[0] = 16777215; // this value surely takes more than 3 bytes. It cannot fit 1 byte.
    address[1] = 1337; // just for demo, let's put a random other number in the next memory cell.

    printf("%i\n", address[0]); // Prints 16777215. How?! Didn't we overwrite a part of the number?

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this work? Does `malloc` actually allocate more than the number of bytes that we pass to it?

#### EDIT

Thanks for the comments! But I wish to note that being able to write to unassigned memory is **not the part that surprises me** and it's **not part of the question**. I know that writing out of bounds is possible and it is "undefined behavior".

For me, the unexpected part is that the line `address[1] = 1337;` does *not* in any way corrupt the `int` value at `address[0]`.

It seems that the explanations for this diverge, too.

- @Mini suggests that the reason for this is that `malloc` actually allocates more than what's passed, because of cross-platform differences.
- @P__J__ in the comments says that `address[1]` for some reason points to the next sizeof(int) byte, not to the next byte. But I don't think I understand what controls this behavior then, because `malloc` doesn't seem to know about what types we will put into the allocated blocks.

### EDIT 2

So thanks to the comments, I believe I understand the program behavior now.
The answer lies in the pointer arithmetic. The program "knows" that an `address` pointer is of type `int`, and therefore adding `1` to it (or accessing via `address[1]`) gives an address of the block that lies `4` (`sizeof(int)`) bytes ahead.

And if we really wanted, we could move just one byte and really *corrupt* the value at `address[0]` by coercing `address` to `char *` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610311/3523645)

Thanks to all and to @P__J__ and @Blastfurnace in particular!

Comment: Welcome to the wild and wacky world of c development, where it's possible to write into any part of memory even if that is not what you intended.

Comment: C Is like a hotel where you're assigned a room but none of the rooms are locked. You may notice the adjacent room isn't being used by anyone and put your stuff in there, too, but don't be surprised when someone shows up and cleans it out because it's not your room and shouldn't have anything in it.

Comment: Compile with GCC and `-fsanitize=address` and it crashes. Then compile with GCC, `-O3` and `-fsanitize=address` and it stops crashing. Since the *behaviour is undefined*, in the `-O3` case the compiler produces a program that works *as if* the correct amount of memory was allocated...

Comment: This is UB but address[1] does not point to the next byte (char) but to next integer. So writing to address[1] will write to the location of the address[1] + sizeof(int) bytes - not one byte ahead. So writing there cannot overwrite the previous object. So you invoke only the UB by woriting to the unallocated memory but you do not have any chance overwrite the previos object. You nned to learn about pointers and its arithmetic

Comment: @timetowonder "Why does this work?" -->  Did you expect the code to reliably detect the out of array range usage?  What "something else." did you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I tried to clear up what exactly confuses in the edit.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't know about types but `address[1]` absolutely knows about types. It's an `int*` and dereferencing it gives a reference to `int`. The address arithmetic, in this case, works in whole `int` units, `address[1]` is `sizeof(int)` bytes past `address[0]`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh, okay, this makes sense, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

malloc often allocates more than you actually ask for (all system/environment/OS dependent), which is why it works in you scenario (sometimes). However, this is still undefined behavior it can actually allocate only 1 byte (and you are writing to what may not be allocated heap memory).

Comment: Even if malloc allocates surgically, you can still get unlucky/lucky (depending on philosophy) and not see any error.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to explain what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't mandate any kinds of bounds checking on array accesses, and it's possible to overflow storage and write into memory you don't technically own.  As long as you don't clobber anything "important", your code will *appear* to work as intended.

However, the behavior on buffer overruns is *undefined*, so the results will not generally be predictable or repeatable.